# Sixteen Principles of Material Creation

Tags: bhagavata-purana

I read recently in Srimad Bhagavatam (Canto 1 - Chapter 3 - Verse 1) about the creation of the sixteen principles of material action.
I am curious to know more about these but can't find any reference to any text about these sixteen principles.
Could somebody please refer me to a scripture which talks about these 16 principles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are as follows:

- 10 Indriyas (senses) i.e 5 Jnanendriya and 5 Karmendriyas
- Mana (Mind)
- 5 Mahabhuta i.e Prithivi, Jala, Aakash, Agni & Vayu

Quoting English translation from [Bhagvata.org](http://bhagavata.org/canto1/chapter3.html#Text%201):

> Sûta said: "In the beginning the Supreme Lord assumed, for the creation of the worlds, the form of the Original Person[: the integrity of the material realm] composed of the sixteen [elements](http://bhagavata.org/glossary/e.html#Elementen) [of the **ten knowing and working senses, the mind and the five elements**] and the cosmic intelligence
>
> Elements (dhâtavah): the essential parts of existence; water, fire, earth, air and ether. Also the seven essential ingredients of the body are dhâtava: skin, flesh, sinew, marrow, bone blood and fat [mentioned in 2.6: 1]. In a broader sense one also speaks of sixteen elements together with the intelligence and the ten working and perceiving s e n s e s. There are also divisions with 24 or 25 elements: the material elements, the subtle elements (the five objects of the senses: odor, color, taste, touch and sound), the ten senses of perception and action, spirit, intelligence, ego and consciousness with the element of time as the twenty-fifth element (see also P r a d h â n a and S.B.: 3-26:11-15, 6.1:50). There is also the nine t a t t v a s.

You can also read the purpot from [Vedabase](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/1) which states:

> Primarily this mahat-tattva is divided into sixteen parts, **namely the five gross material elements and the eleven working instruments or senses.**